# Creating each method for custom two dimensional array

Tags: ruby, each, sparse-array

I followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144822/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-in-ruby) to create a custom class for two dimensional arrays.

```
class SparseArray
  attr_reader :hash

  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def [](key)
    hash[key] ||= {}
  end

  def rows
    hash.length   
  end

  alias_method :length, :rows
end
```

How can I modify this class so I can iterate through the first and second level of an object using Object#each do? Please explain in simple terms, I'm a newbie.

Example of how I would use the each method on an object:

```
sparse_array[0][0] = "row 1 column 1"
sparse_array[0][1] = "row 1 column 2"
sparse_array[1][0] = "row 2 column 1"

sparse_array.each do |row|
  # sparse_array[0] on first iteration
  row.each do |column|
    # sparse_array[0][0] on first iteration
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `each` method on your `SparseArray` and use it to wrap `values` of the wrapped hash:

```
def each &block
  @hash.values.each(&block)
end
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Is there a way to return "" or " " for values that have no entry (e.g. if sparse_array[0][1] has no value assigned)?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. First, `each` will not traverse values with no entry. Second, `each` does not return values at all.

Comment: True, thx for clarifying. Another question, how can I change it to be used as `sparse_array.each_with_index do |value, index|`? Thx

Answer (score 1):

`Hash` has an `each` method as well:

```
hash.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} #{value}" }
```

But if you want a nicer method, put this in your class:

```
def each(&block)
  hash.each do |row,column_hash|
    column_hash.each do |column, value|
      block.call(row,column,value)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
sparse_array.each do |row, column, value|
  puts "row: #{row}, column: #{column}, value: #{value}"
end
```

Comment: 2cents: put `value` first, so you can do `sparse_array.each{|v| puts v}`